# Why isn't G1 freeing memory?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a java 11 app running in a docker container with the following flags:

```
-XX:CICompilerCount=12
-XX:ConcGCThreads=3
-XX:+FlightRecorder
-XX:G1ConcRefinementThreads=13
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4194304
-XX:GCDrainStackTargetSize=64
-XX:InitialHeapSize=1052770304
-XX:MarkStackSize=4194304
-XX:MaxHeapSize=16823353344
-XX:MaxNewSize=10091495424
-XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=4194304
-XX:NonNMethodCodeHeapSize=7594288
-XX:NonProfiledCodeHeapSize=122031976
-XX:ProfiledCodeHeapSize=122031976
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=251658240
-XX:+SegmentedCodeCache
-XX:+UseCompressedClassPointers
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-XX:+UseFastUnorderedTimeStamps
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

What happens is that the memory usage shown by `docker stats` gets very high (7Gb) under load. This is already strange because, although I create a lot of objects, they should be garbage collected on the fly since the objects are not linked to each other and I am not keeping any reference to those objects (I am just iterating over an iterator). Anyway, when the load stops, all those objects should be garbage collected, but what I see is that the memory usage reported stays constant (7Gb).
Only when I run `jcmd 1 GC.run` do I see the memory usage going down to about 1Gb.

I suspected that the GC might not run for some reason so I turned on the GC log with `-Xlog:gc`, but it turns out that it is running as expected:

```
[236.335s][info][gc] GC(14) Concurrent Cycle
[236.352s][info][gc] GC(15) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 84M->81M(124M) 4.344ms
[236.361s][info][gc] GC(16) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 85M->84M(124M) 2.911ms
[236.370s][info][gc] GC(17) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 88M->87M(124M) 2.207ms
[236.380s][info][gc] GC(18) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 91M->89M(124M) 2.192ms
[236.390s][info][gc] GC(19) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 93M->92M(124M) 2.139ms
[236.400s][info][gc] GC(20) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 96M->94M(124M) 2.191ms
[236.409s][info][gc] GC(21) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 98M->96M(124M) 2.132ms
[236.418s][info][gc] GC(22) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 100M->99M(124M) 2.139ms
[236.426s][info][gc] GC(23) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 103M->101M(124M) 2.121ms
[236.435s][info][gc] GC(24) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 105M->104M(124M) 2.075ms
[236.441s][info][gc] GC(14) Pause Remark 106M->106M(124M) 3.191ms
[236.447s][info][gc] GC(25) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 108M->106M(124M) 2.184ms
[236.456s][info][gc] GC(26) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 110M->108M(568M) 3.698ms
[236.491s][info][gc] GC(14) Pause Cleanup 122M->122M(568M) 0.141ms
[236.493s][info][gc] GC(14) Concurrent Cycle 157.955ms
[236.827s][info][gc] GC(27) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 260M->141M(568M) 19.249ms
[237.196s][info][gc] GC(28) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 289M->142M(568M) 19.387ms
[237.441s][info][gc] GC(29) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 302M->144M(568M) 12.322ms
[237.531s][info][gc] GC(30) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 192M->143M(1704M) 14.226ms
[238.441s][info][gc] GC(31) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 699M->157M(1704M) 23.429ms
[238.763s][info][gc] GC(32) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 241M->197M(1704M) 44.961ms
[239.907s][info][gc] GC(33) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1201M->274M(1704M) 57.209ms
[240.671s][info][gc] GC(34) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1198M->344M(3596M) 88.736ms
[error] ErrorHandler - An error occurred (404): 
[241.836s][info][gc] GC(35) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1360M->434M(3596M) 91.769ms
[242.729s][info][gc] GC(36) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1518M->490M(3596M) 95.333ms
[243.834s][info][gc] GC(37) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 1594M->481M(3596M) 51.726ms
[245.636s][info][gc] GC(38) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2545M->490M(6108M) 46.050ms
[249.053s][info][gc] GC(39) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4054M->500M(6108M) 46.525ms
[251.903s][info][gc] GC(40) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4052M->498M(6108M) 41.389ms
[254.797s][info][gc] GC(41) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4054M->495M(6108M) 44.757ms
[257.506s][info][gc] GC(42) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4051M->484M(6108M) 35.766ms
[260.329s][info][gc] GC(43) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4052M->487M(6108M) 34.923ms
[263.337s][info][gc] GC(44) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4051M->472M(6108M) 30.865ms
[266.368s][info][gc] GC(45) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4052M->481M(6108M) 35.517ms
[269.631s][info][gc] GC(46) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4053M->491M(6108M) 39.524ms
[272.931s][info][gc] GC(47) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4051M->484M(6108M) 37.010ms
[info] c.HomeController - Redirecting to swagger generated API
[276.067s][info][gc] GC(48) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4052M->485M(6108M) 38.312ms
[279.409s][info][gc] GC(49) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 4053M->479M(6108M) 33.003ms
[308.226s][info][gc] GC(50) Pause Full (Diagnostic Command) 1220M->51M(256M) 652.015ms
```

So the question is why isn't the memory usage dropping since it looks like G1 appears to be freeing memory as expected. And why does `jcmd 1 GC.run` free the memory effectively??

**EDIT**

I tried with CMS GC instead (`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`) and... no memory issue at all! The memory is freed on the fly as expected (max mem usage 1.5Gb). So I assume now that the issue was G1 was that it was not my application which was using 7Gb, but rather that G1 itself was the culprit (using 6Gb). But why???

Comment: G1GC has a max pause time goal. Doing a 652ms long Full GC violates that goal. As long as you don’t experience `OutOfMemoryError`s, you don’t have a “memory issue”. There’s always a trade off between maximum performance (aka throughput), responsiveness, and memory allocation. You told the JVM that it is ok to use up to ~16GB and it uses half of it to achieve the responsiveness goal. You can use a different GC algorithm or different options to sacrifice responsiveness for using less memory. The decision is yours.

Comment: "You told the JVM that it is ok to use up to ~16GB and it uses half of it to achieve the responsiveness goal." Facepalming me right now. I tried with setting -Xmx, and G1 managed perfectly to stay within the limit.

Answer (score 0):

As Holger explained: since I limit the heap size to 16Gb, G1 took the freedom to use as much memory as it wanted within this limit. Setting Xmx to 4Gb, I could see that G1 was managing to stay under 4Gb, which means non memory issue!